# Your submission is non-compliant

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

from the Windows Dev Center I got the message: 
The app must be testable ...

I looked at  the MS websites but could not found tips that can help me.

My App runs on my Lumnia 930 without any problems. No crashes at all. I use it every day.
I run the test  PROJECT >  Store > Launch …  and everything is OK.
I don't use login credentials or access to a server and my app uses no gift card balance.
In the app I use only simple controls (Buttons and TextBoxes) no sensors.
The C# code woks fine since the good old days with Win Mobile.

Comment: It works on *your* phone but what about others? Are you connecting to some server? Is that server visible *outside* your firewall? In one case the *license* page wasn't visible outside the corporate firewall but the developers thought the application was working properly - *they* could see the page.

Answer (score 0):

> The app must be testable. If it is not possible to test your app for any reason, including, but not limited to, the items below, your app may fail this requirement.
>   10.3.1
>   If your app requires login credentials, provide us with a working demo account using the Notes to Tester field.
>   10.3.2
>   If your app requires access to a server, the server must be functional to verify that it's working correctly.
>   10.3.3
>   If your app allows a user to add a gift card balance, give us a gift card number that can be used in the testing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx

But as per your question all the above 3 points are not applicable. A quick search also gave me the following result. So this might be the problem.

> A Windows Phone 7 or 8 application may run flawlessly during development and testing, but after submitting it for certification testing, the application may crash or perform unexpectedly. Along these same lines, your application may not perform as expected after publication. This article explains the most common reasons for this, along with remedies.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2859130

Were there any comments by the tester? In my experience the tester's give really detailed comments which help resolve any issues that may be there.

Comment: In fact #2 may well be the problem - the server is visible inside the corporate network but not visible outside it. I know of at least one case where the *license page* wasn't visible outside the network but the devs hadn't noticed.

Comment: I sent them a support ticket  with further information’s but got only general information’s back.
All I know is “The App silently terminates at launch” and “Tested Devices: 1020.”

Comment: Well that isn't very helpful. Is it possible for you to test it on more devices? Or multiple emulators at least, which have different configurations